# WPF+Datagrid+CellUpdate: How to programmatically implement

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF application. Like this:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="MetroDataGrid"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      CanUserResizeRows="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                      Margin="1"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      HeadersVisibility="All"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Invoicelines, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      CanUserSortColumns="False"
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow">
```

Where Invoicelines is a ObservableCollection property in my viewmodel class.

This grid contains three columns: two of them must be summarized and the third column should contains the result.

Notice that my ViewModelClass now implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I tried CellEditEnding event, and still I cannot get, for ths specifid row of the datagrid, the third cell updated from thw two previous cells.

How can you resolve this?

**EDIT (working partially.. Now the problem is because I've attached Cantidad properyy for all a column, then all the rows when change the cell in this columns, pass this change to the rest of the rows in the same column...
what else am I missing?)**

**XAML**

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cant." 
                                        Width="100"
                                        MinWidth="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding DataContext.Cantidad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                                    Minimum="0"
                                                    Interval="0.5"
                                                    StringFormat="0.000"
                                                    HideUpDownButtons="True"
                                                    ></Controls:NumericUpDown>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class InvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<InvoiceLine> invoicelines;

    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceLine> Invoicelines{
        set {
            invoicelines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Invoicelines");
        }
        get { return invoicelines; }
    }

    public decimal Cantidad {
        get { return cantidad; }
        set {
            if (Equals(value, cantidad)) return;
            cantidad = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal Preciounit {
        get { return preciounit; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, preciounit)) return;
            preciounit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public decimal Preciounit { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried with the first column like this: `<DataTemplate> <Controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Cantidad2}"></Controls:NumericUpDown> </DataTemplate>`. But still when I debug the compiler is not getting into the Cantidad2 property.. am I missing something?

If you are using the NumericUpDown from MahApps you should try to set the UpdateSource property of the binding to PropertyChanged:

```
<controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Cantidad2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Then the setter of the Cantidad2 property should get invoked provided that the data object in your "Invoicelines" collection actually has a property named "Cantidad2" of the appropriate type (which is probably `double` depending on the NumericUpDown Control you are using).

**Edit:** If you want to bind to a property of the InvoiceViewModel class you should use a RelativeSource:

```
<controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding DataContext.Cantidad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```

Comment: Hi..
Post updated with the source code... still is not working to catch the property into the ViewModel class.

Comment: I see no "Cantidad" property? Shouldn't you bind to the "Preciounit" property? What's the type of your "Invoicelines" source collection?

Comment: Hi.. source code updated.. do you think Im missgin something?

Comment: Are you trying to set the Cantidad property of the InvoiceLine class or the InvoiceViewModel class?

Comment: Good point!! the control is going to the Get method of the model class... but I need to point to the method in te ViewModel class...

Comment: Use a RelativeSource binding then. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunatelly I faced the problem that because all the lines of thegrid are attached to the same datacontext property, when I change the value of the cell of one gridline, the rest of the lines are changing in the same way... why?

Comment: In other words... when the row changes, that propery must be initialized  to zero...how to do it?

Comment: Of course the values will change across all lines since they all bind to the very same property...you only have one view model with one Cantidad property so this is very much the expected behaviour. If you want a value per row you should bind to the property of the InvoiceLine class, i.e. remove the {RelativeSource ...}.

Comment: An that InvoiceLine class should implemente : INotifyPropertyChanged, right?

Comment: If you bind to any of its properties from somewhere else and you want these elements to be refreshed, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to make changes to first two columns and display result to third column.

Where does your computation logic reside?

You can bind the first two with VM properties and third with computed value (one way binding).

When values of the first two properties is updated, the value of third is automatically updated. You need to raise `PropertyChanged` event in all three.

```
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FirstValue">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstValue}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SecondValue">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondValue}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ThirdValue">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThirdValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Hi Xlr8. I tried with the first column like this:
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Controls:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Cantidad2}"></Controls:NumericUpDown>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
But still when I debug the compiler is not getting into the ``Cantidad2`` property.. am I missing something?

Comment: Hi..
Post updated with the source code... still is not working to catch the property into the ViewModel class.